# open second dropdown after select first - semantic ui

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

i have a semantic ui dropDown that show country cities and another dropdown (semantic) that show regions of cities. after select first dropdown, a ajax request send and get regions of selected city. now i need to force open second dropDown authomatically when first dropDown selected and ajax request responsed ( just jquery ).

this is first dropDown

```
<select class="ui search dropdown">
   <option value="">select city</option>
   <option value="1">city1</option>
   <option value="2">city2</option>
   <option value="3">city3</option>
   <option value="4">city4</option>
   <option value="5">city5</option>
</select>
```

and this is region dropdown

```
<select class="ui search dropdown">
  <option value="">select region</option>
  <option value="1">region1</option>
  <option value="2">region2</option>
  <option value="3">region3</option>
  <option value="4">region4</option>
  <option value="5">region5</option>
</select>
```

please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set id of dropdowns to be use as selector

```
<select id="citydropdown" class="ui search dropdown">
   <option value="">select city</option>
   <option value="1">city1</option>
   <option value="2">city2</option>
   <option value="3">city3</option>
   <option value="4">city4</option>
   <option value="5">city5</option>
</select>
```

And this is region dropdown

```
<select id="regiondropdown" class="ui search dropdown">
    <option value="">select region</option>
    <option value="1">region1</option>
    <option value="2">region2</option>
    <option value="3">region3</option>
    <option value="4">region4</option>
    <option value="5">region5</option>
</select>
```

After loading data of region dropdown toggle region dropdown as follow

```
$('#regiondropdown').toggle();
```

Comment: thanks mr ebrahimi, (mochaker :d) . $(id).dropdown('toogle'); is true ... .